# Undefined variable: prodyy (View: D:\OSPanel\domains\111\resources\views\main-qaz.blade.php)

Tags: laravel5

Вот код в котором ошибка:

```
@isset($prod)
                        @foreach ($prod as $prods)
                        <div class="item">
                            <div class="product-thumb transition">
                                <div class="image product-imageblock"> <a href="{{ route('products.show', ['product' => $prods->id]) }}"><img src="{{ asset('/storage/' . $prods->file) }}" alt="iPod Classic" title="iPod Classic"

 class="img-respons
                                    <div class="caption product-detail">
                                        <h4 class="product-name">{{$prods->name}}</h4>
                                        <p class="price product-price">&#8381 {{$prods->price}}  <span class="price-old">{{$prods->old_price}}</span></p>
                                        <div class="rating">Sale:  {{$prodyy}}%</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @endforeach
                            @endisset
```

Где я ошиблась?

Answer (score 0):

Что бы справлятся с такими вопросами при разработке нужно в первую очередь понять что написанно в описании ошибки, а в этом случае написанно "Неопределённая переменная prodyy на странице", если использовать поиск, то мы найдём её встроке:

```
<div class="rating">Sale:  {{$prodyy}}%</div>
```

Ошибка заключается в том, что у неё нет, как это принято, дефолтного значения в случае если она не определенна! У вас есть @isset($prod) для переменной $prod, а для $prodyy нет. Исправить это можно с помощью такой конструкции:

```
{{ $proddy ?? 'Default' }}
```

Более подробную информацию можно найти здесь (https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/blade#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, пожалуйста примите его!